# How do I setup an Oracle Dynamo Admin Server?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, atg, atg-dynamo

I am confused by Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/CRS.93/ATGCRSInstall/html/s0307atgdynamoserveradmin01.html) on how to setup the (ATG) Web Commerce available on the edelivery website.

I would like to get to the step where I have properly set up the admin console.

Running the bin files on a server seems not work for various reasons:

- either installation finishes but nothing is working

OR

- the installation endlessly asks for arbitrary input.

Also, I want to know if it is possible to setup the server in docker and/or an Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of steps involved in getting the `ATG` Admin Server up and running. These start with installing a JDK, Application Server and provisioning a database. Once you have gone through the Installer (which you downloaded from the *edelivery* site) you need to go through a basic setup process using the `CIM` tool. The installation process (for `ATG 11.3.1`) is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E94707_01/Platform.11-3-1/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0201installationprocedure01.html), while the steps to setup a basic application is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E94707_01/Platform.11-3-1/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0206addingmodulestoyourapplication01.html).

Working through the steps in the `CIM` tool, you will end up with a *deployable* .ear file that you can copy to your application server. Once your application server is started, you will be able to access the Dynamo Admin server.

As of version 11.3.1 `ATG` is officially supported on [Docker](https://commercepros.org/2019/01/09/oracle-commerce-on-premise-release-version-11-3-1-summary/). Considering that you compile your own .ear file and it can be deployed to an Application Server (such as `Weblogic`), `Docker` support won't necessarily provide you with an *ATG Image*. It will simply allow you to run your compiled artefact on a `Docker` container. You are more likely wanting to get hold of a [Weblogic Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-weblogic-server-12c) and deploy your `ATG` artefact there.